# Why is $(1+\frac{3}{n})^{-1}=(1-\frac{3}{n}+\frac{9}{n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ and how to get around the Taylor expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> Let be $(u_n)$ a real sequence such that $u_0>0$ and that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n+1}{n+3}$$
>
> Let be $(v_n)$ a real sequence such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$v_n=n^2u_n$$
>
> Let's determine the nature of $\sum\ln(\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n})$

I did:
\begin{align*}
\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n} &=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\frac{n+1}{n+3}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{-1}\\
\end{align*}

and there I was stuck. A friend of mine gave me this tip:

$$=\left(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}+\frac{9}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$

But I don't understand this notation $o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ I know that it means that its negligible. I checked on wikipedia that it *describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity*

But still, I'm stuck:

1. what does that mean, how do we end up to it?

I think it is related to the Taylor expansion of $\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{-1}$

because $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha -1)}{(2)!}x^2 + x^n\epsilon(x)$

then $\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{-1}=...$

but still I'm not very smart at usual Taylor developments so...

2. is there a way to get around?

Comment: $\sum \ln(v_{n+1}/v_n)$ is telescopic..

Comment: This equation doesn't seem quite right: $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=(\frac{n+1}{n})^2\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Because the original intent was to write $$\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2 \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n},$$ which is clear from the context of the definition of $v_n$ from $u_n$.

Comment: @heropup Your psychic abilities are better than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I don't understand this notation $\displaystyle o\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)$*

A general term $u_n$ is considered as being $\displaystyle o\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)$ if it is such that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\dfrac{u_n}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\to 0.
$$
One may recall that, by the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one has
$$
\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2+o(x^2),\tag1
$$ here again, the notation $o(x^2)$ means any function $f$ satisfying, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}\to 0.
$$

Then, to obtain an asymptotic expansion of $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{-1} $, you may use $(1)$ with $x=\dfrac3n$, observing that as $n \to \infty$ we have $x \to 0$, giving
$$
\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{-1}=1-\frac{3}{n}+\frac{9}{n^2}+o\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)
$$ as given by your friend.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm understanding a bit better the "petit o" notation!

Comment: @Marine1 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As jordan's comment notes, the sum is telescoping:  $$\begin{align*} \sum_{n=1}^N \log \frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n} &= \sum_{n=1}^N \log v_{n+1} - \log v_n \\ &= \log v_{N+1} + \sum_{n=2}^{N} \log v_n - \sum_{n=2}^N \log v_n - \log v_1 \\ &= \log v_{N+1} - \log v_1 \\ &= \log \frac{v_{N+1}}{v_1}. \end{align*}$$  Next, it is easy to see that $$\frac{u_{N+1}}{u_1} = \prod_{n=1}^N \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \prod_{n=1}^N \frac{n+1}{n+3} = \frac{(2)(3)}{(N+2)(N+3)}.$$  Therefore, the finite sum is $$\log \frac{(N+1)^2u_{N+1}}{u_1} = \log \frac{6(N+1)^2}{(N+2)(N+3)},$$ and the limit as $N \to \infty$ is simply $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \log \frac{6(N^2 + 2N + 1)}{N^2 + 5N + 6} = \log 6 + \lim_{N \to \infty} \log \frac{1 + 2N^{-1} + 1N^{-2}}{1 + 5N^{-1} + 6N^{-2}} = \log 6. $$

Comment: Nice solution. However, that is not the problem in the original question....

Comment: @ByronSchmuland The original post **specifically** asks in part 2, "Is there any way to get around?"  This is the part of the question I addressed.

Comment: No, you are looking at a different sum.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland There is an additional typographic error:  the original post did not enclose the subscript $n+1$ correctly; based on their own work, it is also clear that the intent was to evaluate $$\sum \log \frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n},$$ rather than $$\sum \log \frac{v_n + 1}{v_n},$$ which I agree is very different.