# Is this method of demonsterating converegence of series false?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let be $(u_n)$ a real sequence such that $u_0>0$ and that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n+1}{n+3}$$
>
> Let be $(v_n)$ a real sequence such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$v_n=n^2u_n$$
>
> Let's determine the nature of $\sum\ln(\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n})$

Why shouldn't we do:

\begin{align*}
\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}&=\frac{(n+1)^2u_{n+1}}{n^2u_n}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^2(n+3)}\\
&=\frac{n^3+3n^2+3n+1}{n^3+3n}\\
&=\frac{n^3(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})}{n^3(1+\frac{3}{n^2})}\\
&=\frac{(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})}{(1+\frac{3}{n^2})}
\end{align*}

which has a limit of 1 $\Rightarrow$  $\ln(\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n})$ as a limit of 0, then its series converges?

And rather do what was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597780/why-is-1-frac3n-1-1-frac3n-frac9n2o-frac1n2-and)?

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$, then not necessarily $\sum_{n} a_n < \infty$. Take for instance $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, so that it why there needs to be more work.

Comment: Okay, I understand! $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges but $\frac{1}{n}\overbrace{\longrightarrow}^{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The right path to the answer should be: $\ln\left(\dfrac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^2(n+3)}\right)=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{3n+1}{n^3+3n^2}\right)\leq \dfrac{3n+1}{n^3+3n^2} < \dfrac{4}{n^2}\Rightarrow \text{the series converges by comparison test}$

Comment: yes there was a $3n$ instead of a $3n^2$ well done